# Downloading set of XML files as a zip file in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I have a String Array in which each string contains some xml content.I have to put each string into a file and finally have to download all xmls as a zip file.

How can we achieve it using JSF.

Example code:

```
String content="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Head>
<Car>
    <model>i10</command>
    <price></target>

</car></Head>";
 HttpServletResponse response =
               (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                   .getExternalContext().getResponse();
       ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
       ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry("spy.log");
       zos.putNextEntry(ze);

       zos.write(content.getBytes());
       zos.closeEntry();


       response.setContentType("application/zip");

       response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=fyi.zip");
       response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
       response.getOutputStream().flush();
       response.getOutputStream().close();
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

But i am unable to download it as an attachment.Please guide me!!

Comment: Please elaborate "i am unable to" in developer's perspective instead of in enduser's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The headers must be done first. *(As in HTTP the header lines are written first, and then the content.)*

`content.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Do not close the response output stream. Call `zos.finish()` at the end (does not close as opposed to `zos.close()` - one of both have to be called for a zip). Closing the response output stream is the responsibility of the container.

*(Make sure nothing is output besides the code above.)*

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to use response.addHeader instead of response.setHeader?

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=fyi.zip");
response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is utter nonsense. In future answers wherein you do seemingly a blind shoot in the dark, at least elaborate constructively and sensibly *why* you thought that it would possibly fix the problem. Otherwise it look too much like that you've no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I have compared this example with a working code and in my code I used the addHeader. If I see a Method setHeader I would suggest that this method set the Header and possible remove old values. The Method-name addHeader should add the additional information. But I dont know if this is so in this case. Sorry, but this was a blind shoot int the dark, but I only want to help :-)